# UNIT TEST: How can I use Unit Test for Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

If whole of my codes only distribute data to database or get data from database, how can I use Unit Test for that?
While on https://codeutopia.net/blog/2015/03/01/unit-testing-tdd-and-bdd/ says :

> A Unit Test should be isolated from dependencies – for example, no network access and no database access.

Comment: Mock your database.

Comment: You should have a layer of abstraction between your business logic and the data access (repository pattern is one example). Then you can mock that layer without changing the logic layer. If your code is not designed to be tested you may benefit from [my blog post on "just enough" mocking](https://contrivedexample.com/2016/11/26/testing-the-un-testable/)

Comment: @Maarten thanks sir, but i don't know how to mock database.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks sir, I will visit your blog.

Answer (score 1):

Stub out only the calls to DB or any other external resource. then all your code block will get covered. If there are codes which shouldn't be part of unit test then exclude them from code coverage using a [*Run Setting*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) file

Comment: I dont understand, sir. but I will learn more.